# How to get data daily for each shift

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to return data per shift for each day of the week for two years . Each day has two 12hr shifts. Day Shift (6am to 6pm) Night Shift (6pm to 6am). In the attached picture below is the results I am looking for. Each columns 1DayGas and 1NightGas represents one piece of equipment for each shift. (Not day 1). With the select statement below it doesn't give me the data I am looking for. It returns the data for just today.

```
SELECT DateTm, FurnNbr, sum(usage) Total
FROM GasUsage
Where DateTm >= cast(getdate() as date)
and DateTm < cast(getdate()+1 as date) and FurnNbr > 0
Group By DateTm, FurnNbr Order By FurnNbr
```

This one gives me dayshift by furnace totals.

```
SELECT FurnNbr, sum(usage) Dayshift
FROM GasUsage
Where DateTm >= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),110)) and DateTm <= DATEADD(HOUR,18,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,110)) and FurnNbr > 0
Group by FurnNbr
```

[image]

[image]

Dayshift results by furnace.
[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Specify the expected result as well, having the given table data.

Comment: the picture shows the expected results

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your where statement only selects lines lines from today

*Where DateTm is newer that "today" AND DateTm is older that "tomorrow" AND FurnNbr larger than 0*

You could try using "between" insted ,it's easier to read.
*...Where DateTM is Between "Date1" AND "Date2"*

If you post how the data in the is structured in the GasUsage table ,it's easier to help.

Comment: I added how the data looks to the original post. In the where clause I am know that it only returns the results for today, that was just an example to just show

Comment: what column identifies the different shifts?

Think my first approach would be to use Pivot to get the data displayed like you want.
[Pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I am just going off DateTm to determine each shift. Dayshift 6am to 6pm, Nightshift 6pm to 6am.